# UITouch returns UIWebBrowserView (Apple internal component) instead of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitouch, uievent

I have a UIWebView and I want to detect any touch on that. (I don't want to use UITapGsture or any other thing)

I am using sendEvent: method of UIApplication for this purpose 
and check if touch object contains webview.

Surprisingly it points to UIWebBrowserView. I have to check it's superview to get browser but it makes my code very inefficient because sendEvent is called every time when user makes a tap.

Code Snippet :

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    if (touches.count != 1)
        return;
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject

    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){ // This fails

    }
}
```

I want to know is there a way to make UITouch return WebView as an object instead of returning it's child views like UIPdfView or UIWebBrowser view?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this :

We have to use :

```
if([touch.view isMemberOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){ // This Works

}
```

instead of :

```
if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){ // This fails

}
```

Comment: @dooleyo you can NSLog the description of event that might help you to figure out.